# Convert a drawable object into one of the "Image" function types in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, lazycolumn

I'm building a "Sitcom" app in android studio using lazy columns.
I want to displays rows of sitcom characters as follows - characters image and next to it his name.
I downloaded the jpg-s of all the characters and made a map `((character's name) = key to (character's image) = R.drawable.characterName)` inside my "ImageLoader" function.

```
@Composable
fun ImageLoader(item: String) {

    val characterMap = mapOf("Rachel Green" to R.drawable.rachel, "Ross Geller" to R.drawable.ross,
        "Monica Geller" to R.drawable.monica, "Joey Tribbiani" to R.drawable.joey,
        "Phoebe Buffay" to R.drawable.phoebe, "Chandler Bing" to R.drawable.chandler,
        "Gloria Delgado-Pritchett" to R.drawable.gloria, "Manny Delgado" to R.drawable.manny,
        "Jay Pritchett" to R.drawable.jay, "Claire Dunphy" to R.drawable.claire,
        "Phil Dunphy" to R.drawable.phil, "Haley Dunphy" to R.drawable.haley,
        "Ted Mosby" to R.drawable.ted, "Robin Scherbatsky" to R.drawable.robin,
        "Barney Stinson" to R.drawable.barney, "Lily Aldrin" to R.drawable.lily,
        "Marshall Ericsson" to R.drawable.marshall)

    Image(bitmap = characterMap.get("Rachel Green"),
        contentDescription = "character image",
        contentScale = ContentScale.Fit,
        modifier = Modifier.size(75.dp)
    )
```

As I try to use the "Image" function I can't understand how to convert those drawables into the function's suitble variable types.

Comment: Change `Image(bitmap = characterMap.get("Rachel Green"),` to `Image(painter = painterResource(id = characterMap.get("Rachel Green"),`

Comment: Be aware that you are always hardcoding the same image in the composable ("Rachel Green")

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps!

```
    Image(painter = painterResource(id = characterMap.get("Rachel Green")),
    contentDescription = "character image",
    contentScale = ContentScale.Fit,
    modifier = Modifier.size(75.dp)
)
```

Reference:
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/graphics/images/loading#disk-loading

https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/res/package-summary#painterresource